# Current Network setup of more than 10 PTP connection from different ISPs, After going Azure how to connect them

Tags: networking, connection

Currently I have a full infrastructure setup in my on premises - Oracle database and clients connections.
I have now shifting my database over Azure & hence my all clients should connect to server in Azure but the question is now How my clients connections( current clients connecting from multiple ISPs PTP datalink to my premises server)? I can't tell to all ISPs to make a VPN connection to my new Azure network.

Any Advice will help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I can't tell to all ISPs to make a VPN connection to my new Azure
>   network.

Sure you can. Either [VPN or ExpressRoute circuit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/).

If the application traffic is encrypted (TLS), consider direct over the Internet, without VPN.